# Can Visual Studio Application Settings have a value which refers to another Setting's value?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

For example, I've got Properties.Settings.Default.Foo which has some string as its value, and I'd like to define another setting, let's call it Bar, to be (some_string_literal + Properties.Settings.Default.Foo).

I cannot find a way to do this with the Visual Studio settings designer. Is it possible?

Thanks!